# how do I inject `$rootScope` using TypeScript static injector pattern?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, typescript

So, finally after getting a large model to compile in both angular and typescript, I get this runtime error:

> 10angular.js:12314 Error: [ng:cpws] Can't copy! Making copies of
>   Window or Scope instances is not supported.
>       http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/ng/cpws

```
at angular.js:68
at copy (angular.js:857)
at copy (angular.js:932)
at copy (angular.js:888)
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15666)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:15935)
at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1624)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:4443)
at doBootstrap (angular.js:1622)
at bootstrap (angular.js:1642)
```

I did not change any "implementation" I only re-structured classes to use TypeScript. Nowhere in my code to a use angular.copy (in any classes in the whole app). After much beating my head against the wall, I stumbled across the problem. The constructor assigns $rootScope to a local variable (that due to TS, is now on the prototype). Now, this was kind of old code and I was only using a ref to $rootScope to use it as a generic event dispatcher to all the view controllers using `$rootScope.broadcast(...)`. It used to work fine when I injected it using the standard angular boilerplate, and I could refactor it...

```
/// <reference path="../../app/reference.ts" />
class UserModel {
  roles:string;
  activeRole:string;
  errorString:string;
  loginAttemptEmailValue:string;
  successString:string;

static $inject = ['utils', '$rootScope','$q', '$cookies', '$http','settings', '$location'];
  constructor(u,r,q,c,h,s,l) {
    this.utils = u;
    this.rootScope = r; // <---- the problem. comment-out this line and it works.
    this.q = q;
    this.cookies = c;
    this.http = h;
    this.settings = s;
    this.location = l;
  }
...

angular.module('App').service('userModel', UserModel );
```

**But this makes me concerned** that when I go to convert my controllers I will have the same problem just injecting $scope.

So, my question is, how do I properly inject `$scope` using this TypeScript static injector pattern without getting this dreaded copy error?

I tried making a class-level static scope variable, but of course you get a left-hand assignment error trying to assign to a static type.

**UPDATE:** 
Here's the transpiled js.

```
var UserModel = (function () {
    function UserModel(u, r, q, c, h, s, l) {
        var _this = this;

        this.utils = u;
        this.rootScope = r;
        this.q = q;
        this.cookies = c;
        this.http = h;
        this.settings = s;
        this.location = l;
    }
    UserModel.prototype.hasActiveRole = function (val) {
        if (this.activeRole === val) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
    //...other implementation...
    UserModel.$inject = ['utils', '$rootScope', '$q', '$cookies', '$http', 'settings', '$location'];
    return UserModel;
})();
angular.module('App').service('userModel', UserModel);
```

Comment: Clarification request: if you comment out `this.rootScope = r;` then your app still runs fine (minus the broadcast)?

Comment: yep! Its that one line that makes the app immediately error. I can comment it out and get a normal null error later on the program's execution.

Comment: That makes sense, are you able to share the code that is using `$rootScope`. The assignment you have above is correct.

Comment: Right, I only use it to broadcast. `this.rootScope.$broadcast('changeRole');` maybe one other one to broadcast 'loggedOut' or something. I'm attempting to convert a controller to TS at the moment to see how big a deal this actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, answering my own question here should anyone else hit the same brick wall. I believe this condition may be an Angular bug or missing documentation about assigning `$rootScope` to a local variable *in a service*.

Injecting `$scope` or `$rootScope` and assigning to a local reference property seems to work fine, **in a controller** but not a service. I also notice that you *cannot* import `$scope` into a service at all, perhaps the angular team meant to also prevent injecting `$rootScope` but neglected to do so.

The error itself is baffling; my best conjecture is that there is an artifact from compilation (deep in the bowels of Angular) wherein instantiation of the service tries to deep copy the `$rootScope` property instead of shallow copy if and only if it is assigned to property on the service object.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you're trying to deep-watch the whole instance of your class. You just shouldn't do this if one of the properties of this object points to a scope instance. If you all the same want to do it, you can try to use a getter function instead of a normal property: `this.getRootScope = () => $rootScope`, which might work but still doesn't sound like a good idea. Because for performance reasons, when you deep-watch something, you want the watched object to be as small as possible. If you just want to detect changes in some data, does it make sense to look for changes in the injected services at the same time? Clearly, you're passing the wrong object to `$watch`.

(BTW, I'd recommend using ngAnnotate instead of writing `static $inject...` by hand.)

Comment: there was no watch. This was simply a problem injecting $rootScope into a service... unless there's some auto-binding of watch that I'm not aware of.

Comment: The stack trace clearly shows there was a watch somewhere, which was tracking the whole `userModel` object. Like that: `$scope.$watch(userModel, ..., true)`.

Comment: I see a digest, but no watch. what are you referring to?

Comment: In fact, the implementation of the consuming controller only watches the one property, loginStatus. this.scope.$watch(() => {
      return this.userModel.loginStatus;
    }, (oldStatus, newStatus ) => {

      if( oldStatus !== newStatus ){
        this.handleLoginStatusChange();
      }

    });

Comment: Digest is the place where watches are processed. `angular.copy` is used by deep watches to store a copy of the value of the watched expression. If `copy` was called directly from `$digest`, it can mean **only** this one thing.

Comment: but this is obviously not bound to the userModel, but the property on userModel. And it's dereferenced by return this.userModel.loginStatus. it is not tracking the whole object (deep set to false, too).

Comment: Some other deep-watched object might hold a reference to userModel. You have the stack trace, the error is reproducible... May the debugger help you.

Comment: I mean, this code was from like 10 sprints ago. pulling the $rootScope out of the service fixed everything with no other code changes.

Comment: Which doesn't mean that injecting $rootScope into a property was the cause of the issue and is something forbidden to do. It's a wrong conclusion.

Comment: So I just searched the entire codebase for $watch and found ZERO deep watches. All watches are a function returning service.property. I tried some experiments and got a result with fat arrow functions raising the error and vanilla function() not raising it.

Comment: I'm actually mystified as to how I was even having this issue. I made this codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EyrAxL that demonstrates watching the WHOLE service (which i don't actually do)... the watch works fine with FALSE and I can't find a single deep:true watch function in the codebase. I was also using an older typescript compiler for grunt back then  and an version older of angular, maybe something was bound differently in the constructor.

Comment: But at least you can see in your codepen that if you replace false with true, you'll get this error.

Comment: You mean you can't reproduce the error with the current version of your code? You inject $rootScope into a property of that service and there is no error? Could it have been some 3rd party library code? Angular's builtin directives don't do deep watches.

Comment: BTW, Angular creates deep watches when object literals are used with `=` and `<` bindings. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kXqKLq?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Have same problem. It is with this thing

```
at Scope.$digest (angular.js:15666)
```

You pass UserModel to angular as service and angular added watchs on every public property, including all this

```
this.utils = u;
this.rootScope = r;
this.q = q;
this.cookies = c;
this.http = h;
this.settings = s;
this.location = l;
```

So when $digest starts it's try to [save value as last](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/1c6edd416b4baad0c8b01148f429eb78e0ad7eaa/src/ng/rootScope.js#L801)

```
watch.last = watch.eq ? copy(value, null) : value;
```

and copy() happens :) that falls with error [because of](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/68f528aa04290609422c0d73eeef2c27c8f9a8f6/src/Angular.js#L863)

```
if (isWindow(source) || isScope(source)) {
  throw ngMinErr('cpws',
    "Can't copy! Making copies of Window or Scope instances is not supported.");
}
```

I temporary solved this with outer variable that stores rootScope for class

```
let rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService;

class Settings() {

  static $inject = [
    '$rootScope'
  ];

  constructor($rootScope: ng.IRootScopeService) {

    rootScope = $rootScope;
  }
}
```

Later will replace $rootScope usage as pub/sub with RxJs Observables